# Column 'django_migrations.id' has unsupported type 'serial' [ with Amazon Redshift]

Tags: python, django, amazon-redshift, django-migrations

I use django_celery with connecting to Amazon Redshift. To migrate database, after "makemigrations" I used command "python manage.py migrate" and error message show up as shown below.

The reason is Redshift does not support data type 'serial' but the 'django_migrations' table that contain 'serial' type is automatically created.

How to stop Django Migrations create this table or avoid using serial on 'django_migrations' table.

```
D:\code\test_celery_django>python manage.py migrate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 330, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 390, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 441, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 93, in handle
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connection, self.migration_progress_callback)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 19, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 47, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 180, in build_graph
    self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 59, in applied_migrations
    self.ensure_schema()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 53, in ensure_schema
    editor.create_model(self.Migration)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 286, in create_model
    self.execute(sql, params or None)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 111, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 79, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 97, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 62, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
django.db.utils.NotSupportedError: Column "django_migrations.id" has unsupported type "serial".
```

Comment: i am seeing the same thing - were you able to figure this out ?

Comment: what database driver are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to use Redshift as the backend database for your web application? That's a bad idea, Redshift is a data warehouse and as such individual query performance and latency are far from great, not to mention that Redshift doesn't enforce primary keys, which almost surely Django expects.

My recommendation, use PostgreSQL.