# Using RedShift as an additional Django Database

Tags: python, django, postgresql, orm, amazon-redshift

I have two Databases defined, `default` which is a regular MySQL backend and`redshift` (using a `postgres` backend). I would like to use RedShift as a read-only database that is just used for [django-sql-explorer](https://github.com/groveco/django-sql-explorer).

Here is the router I have created in `my_project/common/routers.py`:

```
class CustomRouter(object):
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        return 'default'

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        return 'default'

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        db_list = ('default', )
        if obj1._state.db in db_list and obj2._state.db in db_list:
            return True
        return None

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        return db == 'default'
```

And my `settings.py` references it like so:

```
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['my_project.common.routers.CustomRouter', ]
```

---

The problem occurs when invoking `makemigrations`, Django throws an error with the indication that it is trying to create `django_*` tables in RedShift (and obviously failing because of the postgres type `serial` not being supported by RedShift:

```
...
raise MigrationSchemaMissing("Unable to create the django_migrations table (%s)" % exc)

django.db.migrations.exceptions.MigrationSchemaMissing: Unable to create the django_migrations table (Column "django_migrations.id" has unsupported type "serial".)
```

So my question is two-fold:

1. Is it possible to completely disable Django Management for a database, but still use the ORM?
2. Barring Read-Only Replicas, why has Django not considered it an acceptable use case to support read-only databases?

**Related Questions**

*- [Column 'django_migrations.id' has unsupported type 'serial' [ with Amazon Redshift]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31266658/column-django-migrations-id-has-unsupported-type-serial-with-amazon-redshi)*

Comment: @KevinChristopherHenry I'm pretty sure it's happening in the `makemigrations` script, even on a fresh project. In the execute call of the backend, `ensure_backend()` checks if the migrations table exist and I believe creates it if it doesn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just discovered that this is the result of a [bug](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/27054). It's been addressed in a few PRs, most notably: https://github.com/django/django/pull/7194

So, to answer my own questions:

1. No. It's not currently possible. The best solution is to use a custom Database Router in combination with a read-only DB account and have `allow_migrate()` return `False` in the router.
2. The best solution is to upgrade to Django >= 1.10.4 and not use a Custom Database Router, which stops the bug. However, this is a caveat if you have any other databases defined, such as a Read-Replica.